# Java: matrix data type for inserting values based on their coordinates

Tags: java

I've a requirement in which i need to read values and their coordinates and place them into a matrix for displaying it later.

so lets say i've the following:
    `<name='abc', coordinates='1,3'>`
   `<name='xyz', coordinates='2,1'>`
    ...............................

Now i need to put these in a 'matrix collection' based on their coordinate values and get display as table (with cells in the table occupying respective coordinates slot).

Is there a collection/way to do this in java? Mind you, i don't need a swing or any graphic library techniques. I just need a datastructure to do this.

Thank you
BC

Comment: Nothing by default, why not use an array of arrays?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the [Table class](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Table.html) from Guava.

Comment: How did you use that class to achieve your result? I don't see how it would split up your coordinates into two integers. Guava has been recommended regularly in recent answers and it interests me.

Comment: Declare your table as Table<Integer,Integer,Value> and you can treat the indices as coordinates.

Answer (score 1):

If you know in advance the boundaries of your grid, you can use a 2 dimensional array:

```
int[][] matrix = new int [n][n];
```

If you do not, one way to emulate this is with a List of Lists:

```
ArrayList <ArrayList<Integer> > matrix = new ArrayList <ArrayList <Integer> >();
```

Answer (score 1):

Nothing's going to do this automatically for you AFAIK. You'll need to start with extracting the data. Depending on how it's offered to you, you could use regular expressions or some specialized parser (if it's XML, there's a broad selection of tools in Java).

Next up, you're going to need to split that coordinate String. Check [method `split`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) of class `String`.

Finally, those coordinates are gonna need to become integers. Check [method `parseInt`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String%29) of class `Integer`.

With these now numerical coordinates, you can insert the value into an array. If you know the maximum coordinates beforehand, you can immediately create the array. If the coordinates can be any value without bounds, you'll need some dynamic structure or regularly make a larger array and copy over the old contents.